# R convert a column in a table to a list separated by ";"

Tags: list, r

Input

```
gendat <- read.table(textConnection("Gene Treatment1  Treatment2
aaa  bbb         ccc
ddd  eee         fff
ggg  hhh         iii"), header=TRUE)
```

Output for the column "Treatment1"

```
bbb; eee; hhh
```

I want to select only column "Treatment1" and generate a list contains all cells in this column but separated by a ; and a space

Please kindly instruct how to do so with R. Thanks.

Comment: Catherine, sally, whoever, do your own work.  What did _you try_ before posting this question?

Answer (score 3):

I thought ,incorrectly it turns out, that `sep` in paste() could only be one character. You said "list" but I am guessing you did not mean that in the narrow R sense of the term:

```
> paste(gendat$Treatment1, collapse="; ")
[1] "bbb; eee; hhh"
```

Answer (score 2):

R comes with excellent manuals.  I suggest you read "An introduction to R", paying special attention to chapters 2.6 and 6.1

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf